# How can we pass nested requested body which contains file in postman

Tags: spring-boot, model, request, postman, multipart

I have two model files in java spring boot where in one i have declared the variables for database and another one to include file in Request body itself.

I have a controller which takes the request body this. How can i send the following request in postman. Is there better way of doing including a file and my other model class rather than just passing it as request param.

```
public String saveReferenceData(@RequestBody TestClass testClass){
    // custom logic written
    return "done";
```

[image: Model with database fields]
[image: Model nested with file]

Comment: Try passing submission data as request body and file as multipart form data from postman

Comment: We cant do both i believe

Answer (score 0):

You should use multipart request for handling files and text data. Multipart request is similar to any other payload but defined boundaries for server to handle and parse.

## To Upload multipart file In postman:

- Switch to body tab
- select form-data
- add keys
  [image: Multipart]

### Alternative solution

[Dothttp](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ShivaPrasanth.dothttp-code) is similar tool with great control over these.

### For Multipart upload

```
POST https://req.dothttp.dev
// selects as multipart 
multipart(
    'name'< 'john',
    'photo'< 'C:\Users\john\documents\photo.jpg',
// and many more
)
```